# How to create a Java Spring WebApp Folder Structure using Gradle

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, gradle

I am making a Java Web App project using Gradle. Now, for building a Gradle web app plenty of resources are available over the net.

But, my issue is a bit different. Suppose, I want to initiate a Gradle based project and make a web app suitable project folder structure just like we do in maven. Is there any specific way to create so in Gradle. I have found something about templates. Is there any way to do it or do I have to create a folder structure manually and then attach to Gradle so that it can build a war out it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven to create the project and then create gradle build from it:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=java-web-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Then:

```
gradle init --type pom
```

Comment: This is a really good option. Although I was looking for gradle options but this can do the task.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your IDE, but I will answer for IntelliJ IDEA and for Eclipse the steps are similar.

Go to `File --> New --> Project`, choose `Gradle` from the left menu and choose both `Java` and `Web` options (see image below).

[image: steps]

Comment: I was using eclipse. There this 'web' based option was not available and this version of IntelliJ IDEA you are using is probably the paid version. Although this is a good option given someone has the IDE you are using.